# Matlab - Constructing a Cosine wave with IFFT

Tags: matlab, ifft

My apology if following question is too simplistic to be asked but I have the following code which generates a nice `sine` wave for me:

```
N=64;
X=zeros(N,1);
X(2)=-32j;
X(N)=32j;
x=ifft(X);
stem(real(x));
```

[image]

Now I was thinking I should be able to construct a `cosine` wave in the similar way by changing the `X(2)` and `X(N)` values into some real mirrored values say `X(2)=-32` and `X(N)=32`. However, the output is not what I want i.e. a `cosine` wave

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must keep in mind that for a real-valued signal, second half of your spectrum is a **complex conjugate** of all values below the Nyquist frequency. In your case:

```
X(2) = -32
X(N) = 32
```

as you can see the coefficients are not the complex conjugate of each other. Because of that you are ending up with round-off errors, since two frequency components are cancelling each other out.

Here is some modification to your code:

```
clc, clear all, close all
fs = 32;
dt = 1/fs;

N=64;
X=zeros(N,1);
X(2)=32;
X(N)=conj(X(2));
s=ifft(X)';

td = linspace(0, (length(s)-1)*dt,     length(s));

stem(td, s, 'b', 'linewidth', 2)
grid on
legend({'reconstructed signal'})
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So what you changed in my code was basically changing `X(N)=32` into `X(N)=conj(32)` . What's the mathematical interpretation of this? i.e. conjugate of a real value.

Comment: [Complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate)

Comment: conj(32) is 32, so X(N)=conj(32) is the same of X(N) = 32, or did I miss something ? The error of OP was just he did X(2) = -32 instead of X(2) = 32. But I like your way to do it, it prevents errors.

Comment: If you are asking about the line `X(N)=conj(X(2));` then it is there to automatically calculate the coefficient when OP wants to play with the code. Indeed `X(N)` will be 32 in the example above.